# Auto login on web page

Tags: android

I am trying to write an app I want it to open a web page and auto login I am not sure how to go about sending the info to the browser from the app code.

Comment: You need to be way more specific about what exactly you're attempting to accomplish, what steps you've taken so far, etc.

Comment: I have gotten as far as opening the web page in the app, now I need to know how to input the username name and password.

Comment: what I want to do is build a app that will login to a website automatically then access the page. then make buttons that will access different parts of the web page.

Comment: You should include code examples and maybe the html of the login fields that you're trying to access on the actual website.

Comment: Thats my problem not sure where to start?

Comment: <input class="form-control" type="text" name="username" required="">

Comment: browserIntent.GetComponent(//*[@id="txtUName''])

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So basically you are going to need to load in the webpage within a WebView (You can find instructions for that [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) and then probably push javascript into the WebView that will fill in the fields and load the page.

In your activity's `onCreate`:

```
WebView webview = new WebView(this);
setContentView(webview);

webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
   @Override
   public boolean onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
       // Check here if url is equal to your site URL.
   }
});

webview.loadUrl("http://yourwebsite.com/");
```

This line enables javascript in your WebView:

```
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Then you can use the WebViewClient to detect when the page you want has fully loaded. When that happens, you can use:

```
webView.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementsByName('username').value = 'username'");
webView.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementsByName('password').value = 'password'");
webView.loadUrl("javascript:document.forms['login'].submit()");
```

And it should automatically log you in. It's worth noting that this generally isn't easy to do on a lot of sites since they will randomize the login control ids and it also doesn't generally sit well with users if an application is logging into a website automatically for them.

Comment: LOL i was missing the permissions. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: No problem. If this answered your question, be sure to click the checkmark to accept the answer so people know you're not still looking for an answer.

Comment: It's not adding the username or password to the page?

Comment: Are you calling the loadUrl java script calls within the `onPageFinished` method?

Comment: final WebView webview =new WebView(this);
        setContentView(webview);

        webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

                webview.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementByName('username').value = 'username'");


            }
        });




webview.loadUrl("");


    }

Comment: @jyanks thanks, Its working but the thing is that my password is showing for few second in webView before page load. Please let me know how can i resolve that.

Comment: Sounds like a website-specific issue. You could try to call some more javascript functions to disable the password from showing.